# nbsphinx: ipynb output cells need line wrap/break when exporting latex

Tags: pdf, python-sphinx, nbconvert

Using nbsphinx to convert ipynb notebooks to latex for pdf output.  The output cells do not wrap and are cut-off.  My search for a fix has found nothing so far.  The output is relevant and should show up in the report. Thanks.

Comment: which version of Sphinx is used?

Comment: sphinx version 1.7.2